# How to pass OAUTH ACCESS TOKEN credentials to run GCP Dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, credentials

I am trying to create a dataflow pipeline from cloud sdk. I have set environment variable 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN' and I am not sure how to pass this credentials in pipeline.run().

```
def run(argv=None):
    
    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
    google_cloud_options = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    google_cloud_options.project = 'prjoject name'
    google_cloud_options.region = 'region'
    google_cloud_options.job_name = 'jobname'
    google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://staging-location' 
    google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://temp-location' 
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).setup_file = "./setup.py"
    user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(DataInput)


    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    
    input_meta = str(user_options.input)+" "+project+ " "+bucket_name+ " "+ model_path+ " "+destination_name
    header = (p
          | "CREATE BEAM" >> beam.Create([input_meta]) 
          | "Inside read header" >> beam.Map(read_header_from_filename))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I get the following error

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://staging-location/staging/telco-churn-prediction.1633999477.963380/pickled_main_session...
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
INFO:oauth2client.client:Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "reauth related error (invalid_rapt)",
  "error_subtype": "invalid_rapt"
}
```

Comment: How did you authorize this looks like your refresh token has expired.  You need to authorize your code again.   GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN  <-- implies you are setting an access token they are only valid for an hour how are you resetting the access token again?

Comment: Before running my Dataflow python code, I create my GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN so that its fresh and not expired

Comment: Yes but an access token will expire after one hour whats the point of setting an access token as an env var?  Why not follow the  [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python)

Comment: Due to security concerns we are not able to generate authentication Key Files and set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Hi @ChaitanyaPatil, Cloud Dataflow automatically asks for credentials when you run the job. Inside code no authentication required indeed. Can you explain why is it necessary for you to authenticate inside your code?

Comment: You don't have a choice generate GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS you need the credentials in order to identify your application.

Answer (score 2):

When you are running workload on Google Cloud, you don't need specific access token or service account key file. It's better to use standard libraries and ADC. And to customize the [worker service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specifying_a_user-managed_worker_service_account).

Use your own service account, grant the permission that you want and run your pipeline. It's easier and more secure.